# Put GoogleMaps V2 in TabsPagerAadapter?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-maps-v2

I am working on `GoogleMaps v2` and finished it but when put it in `TabsPagerAdpter` this error appeard (**Type missmatch can't convert from MapActivity to Fragment**)

I want to convert `FragmentActivity` to Fragment in Map to support `TabsPageradapter` where tabsPagerAdaper doesn't deal with
FragmentActivity

I try to convert the `MapActivity` class to be extended Fragment but i can't.

**MapActivity class**

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity  {
private static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;

GoogleMap Gmap;
Marker marker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    if (servicesOK()) {
        setContentView(R.layout.ogenia);
        if (initMap()){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Ready to map",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            gotoLocation();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Map not available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map, menu);
    return true;
}
public boolean servicesOK(){
    int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if(isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        return true;
    }
    else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)){
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, this,GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
        dialog.show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"can't connect to Google Play Services",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return false ;
}
private boolean initMap(){
    if (Gmap == null){
        SupportMapFragment mapFrag 
        =(SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        Gmap = mapFrag.getMap();
    }
    return(Gmap != null) ;
}
private void gotoLocation() {
    // Enable my location layer of Google map

            Gmap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            // get LocationManger object from system service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // create criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Get the name of best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            // Get Current Location
            Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            // set map type
            Gmap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            //if (myLocation != null) {

            // Get latitude of the current location

            double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

            // Get longitude of the current location

            double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

            // create latlng object for the current location

            LatLng latlng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            // show the current location in Google map

            Gmap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
            // zoom in Google map
            Gmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));




        /*  if (marker != null) {
                marker.remove();
            }
            Gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                    new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_marker))
                .draggable(true).title("current location")); */


}

 // private void searchLocation(double lat, double lng)
//       {
//  LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
//  Gmap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ll));
            // zoom in Google map
//          Gmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
//}



private void hideSoftKeyboard(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

}





}

}
```

`TabsPagerAdapter` class : error appears in the case 0 ( Type missmatch can't convert from MapActivity to Fragment as **MapActivity class extended FagmentActivity**)

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        // Map fragment activity
         return new MapActivity();
    case 1:
        // Directions fragment activity
        return new Directions();
    case 2:
        // Places fragment activity
        return new Places();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 3;
}

}
```

please help  me

Answer (score 0):

One Suggestion For What You are Doing.Putting Google Map in TabView is bad thinking if the TabView contains the Swiping Functionality.So Both Swipe will Conflict i.e. the Map Swipe & TabView. Hope this will redirect you to correct Path.Thnx

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert an Activity to a fragment, however you can use the MapFragment that is provided by the map library.

Comment: How i can use MapFragment ?

Comment: Have a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment

Comment: i took alook on this topic but i can't understand what can i do or what changes in my code ?

Comment: return new MapActivity(); is wrong because you are trying to cast an activity to a fragment which is totally impossible, so what you could do is create a fragment that extends SupportMapFragment (i.e. MySupportMapFragment), put your logic methods in there (like gotoLocation() and etc...) and then from your adapter return a new MySupportMapFragment() instead of new MapActivity()